# A base of Im (F)

Tags: linear-algebra

Let $V$ and $W$ be two K-vectorial spaces and $F:V\rightarrow W$ a linear map.

Let $ \left \{ v_1, ..., v_n \right \}$ be a base of V.

Then, for a proposition that we have already demonstrated,

the images of the base vectors are independent and

$Im (F)= \left \langle F(v_1), ..., F(v_n) \right \rangle $.

Can I say that $ \left \{F(v_1), ..., F(v_n) \right \}$ is a base of $Im (F)$?

If $dim W<dim V$  how could it be that $F(v_1), ..., F(v_n)$ are linearly independent ?

Comment: What is the "proposition that we have already demonstrated"?

Comment: @Przemek I'm studying from a book in which there is a proposition. It says that is I have a number of linearly independent vectors in V, their images are linearly independent. Now I m confused because the two things are contrasting

Comment: There must be some other conditions in that proposition that you’ve not mentioned, because it’s false as stated. $F:v\mapsto0$ is a simple counterexample.

Answer (score 0):

Only true statement is that $Im(F)=<F(v_1),..,F(v_n)>$. But image of base can be linearly dependent, and even has to if $dimW<dimV$ as you have noticed. With assumption, that $F$ is monomorphism, the set $<F(v_1),..,F(v_n)>$ is indeed base of image. $F$ is monomorphism iff $M_F$ (matrix of that mapping) satisfy $rk(M_F)=dimV$ i.e. rank is equal to dimension of domain.

Comment: I'm trying to understand... if $rk(M_F)=dim V$ ,is F surjective?

Comment: No. Monomorphism means that $F$ is injective, in other words $dimV=dim(Im(F))$. Note that dimension is equal to number of vectors in basis, and it imply that base of image and base of $V$ have the same amount of vectors.

Comment: It is the same thing, if you have $dim V=dim W$ , saying that F is an omomorphism, or is injective or surjective is the same thing, isn't it?

Comment: No, in general $dimV=dimW$ imply nothing. Please check if you understand what iniection and suriection is: [link](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bijection,_injection_and_surjection). Monomorphism is by definition homomorphism that is injective.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rank%E2%80%93nullity_theorem    I' ve used this theorem to say that...

Comment: I'm sorry, I've misread it. You are partially right: if $dimV=dimW$ then every monomorphism is epimpoprhism and vice versa. But still there are homomorphisms that are not injective nor surjective: for example $F(V)=\{0\}$.